# Why does the definition of a rational number have to include the fact that the denominator is non-zero?

Tags: definition, proof-explanation, rational-numbers, integers

A real number $n$ is rational iff $\exists p,q \in \mathbb{Z}, n=\frac{p}{q} \:$ and $q \neq 0$. Why do we need that last condition? Sure, I understand it makes it more clear that a fraction is undefined if the denominator is 0, but this is an existential statement, so if a number is rational, I would think this implies that there exists a $q$ that is nonzero. My reasoning is that if a real number is rational, we can find a $p$ and $q$ that satisfies $n=\frac{p}{q}$, and for this to be possible, $q$ must be nonzero. I’ve lost points on a homework for not mentioning that condition in a proof, so I’m curious why it’s so necessary.

Comment: Are you happy for $\frac{1}{0}$ to be a rational number? Are you happy for an indeterminate form to be a number? An indeterminate form is exactly that: "not exactly known, established, or defined." How can we say it's rational or not rational when its indeterminate?

Comment: @FlybyNight so if this was restricted to if and not iff, would this still be incorrect? That’s why I say “a real number $n$. $\frac{1}{0}$ isn’t a real number.

Comment: The use of "if and only if" is redundant for a definition, one direction is a tautology... by definition.

Comment: @FlybyNight so then if I have this restriction “a real number n” is rational if... then why wouldn’t this exclude all numbers of an indeterminate form?

Comment: If we allow 0, $n$ can be any number, including irrational number so it is essential to say that $q$ is not 0.

Comment: @Vasya can you explain why that is? We shouldn’t a number with a denominator of 0 be indeterminate, and this not satisfying the left side of the implication “a number n is rational if”

Comment: We cannot define real numbers without first defining rational. How do we know what is $\frac{0}{0}$? $n\cdot0=0$ implies that n can be any number.

Comment: "*That’s why I say “a real number* $n$" Technically, when parsed as (a real number $n$ is rational) IF AND ONLY IF (...), I believe you're correct. As for **why** this is done --- habit, unintentionally being non-minimalistic, intentionally being non-minimalistic (for pedagogical reasons), etc.

Comment: "*I’ve lost points on a homework for not mentioning that condition in a proof*" If at the point of the proof in question one already knows the object is a real number, I think you have a valid case. But it depends on what you were proving and how you went about it.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thank you. so the exact context was to define “a real number n is rational if...” and then I didn’t say q not equal to 0, and lost points. So that’s why I was confused. I could see if it said “n is rational if” but the fact is that n is a real number.